# Inverse Thunderbird's Quick filter selection?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

Thunderbird 3.1 has a quick filter bar, very convenient. You click 'starred' and only the starred messages are shown.

Is there some trick or way to also apply the inverse filter, for example show all NOT starred messages?

Edit: I don't want to create a custom filter. I am thinking along the lines of for example alt-clicking the button or so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for Thunderbird 3.1 [states](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_3.1_-_New_Features_and_Changes#Quick-Filter_Bar):

> The Quick-Filter bar is not
>   customizable, but there is a
>   "qfb-pivot" extension to add further
>   search options and a feature to search
>   by properties of the currently
>   displayed message.

But said "qfb-pivot" extension appears to [no longer be available](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/159026/).

---

As an alternative you could consider creating the view filter yourself:

1. Add the view filter widget (Mail Views) to the Thunderbird toolbar.

   [image: View filter widget]
2. Click it, and select "Customize..."

   [image: Customize...]
3. Click "New..."

   [image: Message view setup]
4. Set your new filter up like this:
   Status | isn't | Starred

   [image: The new filter]

Your new filter can then be found under "Custom Views".

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, I was looking for a way to do it using the convenient quick filter bar, creating custom filters is too much of a hassle for one-of things. I'll edit my original question to make it clear

Comment: I kind of assumed that was really what you wanted, and I was disappointed not to find an easy way to do that. Will keep an eye on this question, since I would like to know if that's possible too. Good luck! @Rabarberski

Comment: I should have thought that they'd have opted-out the most useful "view widget" :P

Answer (score 1):

I've found (at least when searching by tags) that if I right-click a tag, it will cross out the label, thus allowing for a NOT function.  Now if I could only figure out a quick-filter version of AND -- clicking multiple tags seems to default as OR.