# Can I use booleans (AND, OR) in Thunderbird's quick filter field?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

Is there a way to use in Thunderbird's quick filter bar to use Boolean filters (like AND, OR, NOT)?

I would like to be able to (for example) search on emails send by either `Joe` OR `Jane`. See below for an example, which obviously doesn't work.

[image]

Note: I don't want to use the "search all messages" options (wonky, slow interface) or "Saved Searches" feature (too cumbersome for one-off searches). So there is no point in suggestion these as a workaround.

Note 2: This is kind of a generalization of my earlier question " [Inverse Thunderbird's Quick filter selection?](https://superuser.com/questions/254867/inverse-thunderbirds-quick-filter-selection) ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full expression searching (including subtraction) is available through an add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmailui/

Comment: THanks for the links. Useful extension. To get the result from my example, I have to type `from:(Joe or Jane)`

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `|` as `OR` operation resp. a space character  as `AND` operation.

Comment: "resp." meaning what exactly?

Comment: resp. == respectively

Comment: What about NOT?

Comment: To remove messages that contain a certain criteria you may use `-`, e.g. `-ft:trump`

Comment: `-` does not seem to work as not. Has it been changed for another character?

Comment: @arauzo maybe kenorb was referring to global search. Go to settings, search for "search", and check "enable global search and indexer"